# What does the "-6" after the name of a Benchmark function mean?

Tags: go, benchmarking

I have a go test file in which I wrote a benchmark function as follows:

```
func BenchmarkStuff(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        stuff()
    }
}
```

When I run this with `go test -benchtime 1x`, I get this:

```
BenchmarkStuff-6               1     847751900 ns/op
```

What does the `-6` mean? It seems unnecessarily cryptic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's indicating the number of CPUs that were used to run the benchmark - so in your case `6`.

---

***EDIT***:

The Benchmark name format does not appear to be formally documented on the Go website, but you can see in the standard library source how the name is formulated [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.16.5/src/testing/benchmark.go#L558) and [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.16.5/src/testing/benchmark.go#L486):

```
runtime.GOMAXPROCS(procs)
benchName := benchmarkName(b.name, procs)

func benchmarkName(name string, n int) string {
    if n != 1 {
        return fmt.Sprintf("%s-%d", name, n)
    }
    return name
}
```

---

FYI: from the `go help` command-line docs:

```
go help testflag
```

> ```
>     -cpu 1,2,4
>         Specify a list of GOMAXPROCS values for which the tests or
>         benchmarks should be executed. The default is the current value
>         of GOMAXPROCS.
> ```

So if you wanted to coerce your benchmarking to use a lower number of CPUs use the env var `GOMAXPROCS`:

```
$ GOMAXPROCS=2  go test -bench=.

...

BenchmarkStuff-2    1000000000           0.2642 ns/op
```

Or you can benchmark multiple CPU core settings like so:

```
$ go test -bench=. -cpu=1,2,4

...

BenchmarkStuff      1000000000           0.2516 ns/op
BenchmarkStuff-2    1000000000           0.2531 ns/op
BenchmarkStuff-4    1000000000           0.2488 ns/op
```

Comment: Do you know of an official source for this answer?

Comment: I meant specifically about the meaning of the `-#` at the end of the benchmark name. It seems incidentally true that it reflects the CPU count, but I'm just struggling to find an explicit documentation of that part of the name formatting. It seems like it might be an undocumented feature.

Comment: It's "documented" in the standard library source :)  See update.

Comment: This probably should be documented somewhere. If there isn't an issue open to update the docs, there should be.

Comment: it is also mentioned in the book "The Go Programming Language"